# Universal Feed Parser issue

Tags: python, xml, rss, feedparser

I am working on a python script to parse RSS links.

I use the [Universal Feed Parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feedparser) and I am encountering issues with some links, for example while trying to parse the [FreeBSD Security Advisories](http://www.freebsd.org/security/rss.xml) 
Here is the sample code:

```
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    items = feed["items"]
```

Basically the feed["items"] should return all the entries in the feed, the fields that start with item, but it always returns empty.

I can also confirm that the following links are parsed as expected:

- [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/rss.xml)
- [Redhat](https://rhn.redhat.com/rpc/recent-errata.pxt)

Is this a issue with the feeds, in that the ones from FreeBSD do nor respect the standard ?

**EDIT:**

I am using python 2.7.
I ended up using feedparser, in combination with BeautifulSoup, like [Hai Vu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459745/hai-vu) proposed.
Here is the sample code I ended up with, slightly changed:

```
def rss_get_items_feedparser(self, webData):
    feed = feedparser.parse(webData)
    items = feed["items"]
    return items

def rss_get_items_beautifulSoup(self, webData):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webData)
    for item_node in soup.find_all('item'):
        item = {}
        for subitem_node in item_node.findChildren():
            if subitem_node.name is not None:
                item[str(subitem_node.name)] = str(subitem_node.contents[0])
        yield item

def rss_get_items(self, webData):
    items = self.rss_get_items_feedparser(webData)
    if (len(items) > 0):
        return items;
    return self.rss_get_items_beautifulSoup(webData)

def parse(self, url):
        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        webData = response .read()
        for item in self.rss_get_items(webData):
            #parse items
```

I also tried passing the response directly to rss_get_items, without reading it, but it throws and exception, when BeautifulSoup tries to read:

```
  File "bs4/__init__.py", line 161, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem was with the use of *namespace*.

for FreeBSD's RSS feed:

```
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
     version="2.0">
```

For Ubuntu's feed:

```
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
     version="2.0">
```

When I remove the extra namespace declaration from FreeBSD's feed, everything works as expected.

So what does it means for you? I can think of a couple of different approaches:

1. Use something else, such as BeautifulSoup. I tried it and it seems to work.
2. Download the whole RSS feed, apply some search/replace to fix up the namespaces, then use `feedparser.parse()` afterward. This approach is a big hack; I would not use it myself.

## Update

Here is a sample code for `rss_get_items()` which will returns you a list of items from an RSS feed. Each item is a dictionary with some standard keys such as **title**, **pubdate**, **link**, and **guid**.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def rss_get_items(url):    
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response)

    for item_node in soup.find_all('item'):
        item = {}
        for subitem_node in item_node.findChildren():
            key = subitem_node.name
            value = subitem_node.text
            item[key] = value
        yield item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'http://www.freebsd.org/security/rss.xml'
    for item in rss_get_items(url):
        print item['title']
        print item['pubdate']
        print item['link']
        print item['guid']
        print '---'
```

Output:

```
FreeBSD-SA-14:04.bind
Tue, 14 Jan 2014 00:00:00 PST
http://security.FreeBSD.org/advisories/FreeBSD-SA-14:04.bind.asc
http://security.FreeBSD.org/advisories/FreeBSD-SA-14:04.bind.asc
---
FreeBSD-SA-14:03.openssl
Tue, 14 Jan 2014 00:00:00 PST
http://security.FreeBSD.org/advisories/FreeBSD-SA-14:03.openssl.asc
http://security.FreeBSD.org/advisories/FreeBSD-SA-14:03.openssl.asc
---
...
```

Notes:

- I omit error checking for sake of brevity.
- I recommend only using the `BeautifulSoup` API when `feedparser` fails. The reason is `feedparser` is the right tool the the job. Hopefully, they will update it to be more forgiving in the future.

Comment: I have to parse a few RSS links, do you think BeautifulSoup can handle all variants of RSS ? or maybe use a combination first try with feedparser, if no results use BeautifulSoup .

Comment: I would go with feedparser, then fall back to BeautifulSoup.